# JQuery delayed + queued calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page in which a stream of events with images is displayed in real-time. Since it's in real-time (as the event occurs), it's possible the image isn't quite available yet as it's still being uploaded to storage.

Calls to get new events are executed every couple of seconds, and each call can return up to 20 events (the latest 20), but usually it's between 0 and 5.

Due to the issue of images potentially not loading initially, an `onerror` function is used:

```
<img onerror="retryImage(this, 'imageUrl', 0)" src="imageUrl" />

function retryImage(source, url, attempts) {
    img = new Image();
    img.src = url + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();
    img.onload = function() {
        source.src = img.src;
    };
    img.onerror = function() {
        if (attempts > 4) {
            source.src = 'not_found.png';
        } else {
            source.src = 'loading.gif';
            attempts++;
            $(this).delay(2000).queue(function() {
                retryImage(source, url, attempts);
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
        }
    };
    return true;
}
```

The idea is to attempt to load the image, and if it fails, wait a couple of seconds and try again, up to 5 times.

Unfortunately, in practice every now and then (when a number of images fail to load initially, at the same time), one of the images displayed will belong to a different event. Which leads me to think I'm misusing the `delay()` and `queue()` functions?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed; `delay` and `queue` are intended for use specifically with jQuery effects. Quoting from [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> The `.delay()` method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—`.delay()` is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   `setTimeout` function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

I believe this is precisely such a use case! Try something like:

```
function retryImage(source, url, attempts) {
  img = new Image();
  img.src = url + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();
  img.onload = function () {
    source.src = img.src;
  };
  img.onerror = function () {
    if (attempts > 4) {
      source.src = 'not_found.png';
    } else {
      source.src = 'loading.gif';
      attempts++;
      setTimeout(function () {
        retryImage(source, url, attempts);
      }, 2000);
    }
  };
  return true;
}
```

Comment: FYI - I marked this answer correct as it was correct according to the question (my usage of `.delay()` and `.queue()`) - however it didn't fix the overall issue of incorrect images loading. That issue was due to the 'img' variable being declared globally instead of locally (i.e. `var img = new Image()`)... Silly oversight!